# Ram problem even if they pass the apple hardware test?

Tags: hardware, upgrade, memory, mac-mini, kernel-panic

After updating the ram 2 x 8 GB (CT2KIT102464BF160B) the mac mini late 2012 have started various kernel panic, doing the Apple Harware Test to verify the modules the ram is ok, everything is ok.

So the crashes should not depend on the ram, but by putting the original modules back, everything goes back to work without crashing.

In doubt, however, I started asking for the return of the ram but I wonder and I wonder is it still the ram to cause me problems even if the AHT tells me it's ok?

Comment: Did you run the long tests, or just the short? Long tests can take an hour or so per GB RAM.

Comment: nope, via network it did not seem like a good idea

Comment: Then you haven't fully tested the RAM. You can get USB-bootable versions of the AHT [& instructions] from https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest

Comment: Tanks. Even if I do not see my model of mac mini 6.2 it's interesting, it will serve to test the new ram I will order. I have already done the exorcism 'vade retro satana' ready to ship :)

Comment: Also try something like [Rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/) @Tetsujin Unfortunately not all models are available there, double check to make sure your *board ID* not just your model is there.